# fit image to cell on resize in html email

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

I have an responsive html email design which I did using [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/4240/creating-a-centred-responsive-design-without-media-queries) tutorial from campaign monitor but I have one problem my image is not fitting to the device when it is viewed on mobile,after designing many templates and reading a lot on email designing blogs I learned that gmail by default remove css or styling in the head part and allows only inline html .So now in my case I want my image to fit the device width but its not fitting when I am sending in mail but I can see on browser because of  below coded media query .

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width:300px) {
.col185{max-width:100% !important;}
.col180{max-width: 100% !important;}
.col180 img{
  height: 155px;
 }
}
```

. So what is there any way where in i can see image stretched on my mobile device also. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/AnkitaPalekar/r53aLokq/) is my js fiddle link . [image: this is how it looks on mobile]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the name of the div that contains the image is pic You should do this

CSS

```
.pic img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

This will allow the image to re-size itself according to the parent div. If you still don't understand this method let me know and i'll expand on it

Comment: I would recommend height:auto, to avoid any stretching or squashing.

Comment: My width is 100% of that particular div u can check the code in js fiddle but still its showing the same as above image when i see email on my gmail app on android  app

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to `width` or `min-width`, and right now you have `max-width`. See below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width:300px) {
.col185{min-width:100% !important;}
.col180{min-width: 100% !important;}
.col180 img{
  height: auto;
 }
}
```

Otherwise, you're just saying to use `height: 155px` and width will adjust to that height.

Also, remember that not all mail clients render your CSS the same. Many of them, specially Outlook, won't accept many of your CSS rules. Just to be sure, you can run your code through http://premailer.dialect.ca/ (free) or similar so you can pre-check what will happen with your mail